# Can Extra listeners in Mosquitto MQTT broker help to improve performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, mosquitto

There is a concept of **Extra listeners** in **Mosquitto MQTT broker**. This can be added/configured in the mosquitto.conf file.

I understand that this will enable the broker to listen on multiple ports with different configurations(TLS, web-socket, with password) etc.

Can this be used to increase the performance of the brokers?

For example, If we have to receive million of messages on a cloud based infrastructure, is it a good idea to have an ec2 instance(or similar)  with multiple virtual Ethernet adapters(eg. ENA), and map each listeners to each of the adapters?  For example a t2.large instance in aws can have up to 3 network interfaces.

In short, what is the core idea behind extra listeners? Is it to provide different configurations? or for improving the performance of the brokers?

Does it make sense to use this for handling many requests?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as you said listeners are to allow you to map different protocol (websockets/TLS/MQTT) to different ports/interfaces.

The core of mosquitto is a single threaded event loop handling all messages, adding extra listeners will not change the fact that they all need to pass through this event loop.

Comment: Thank you. Point taken.